# AWS Glue Data Catalog & Spark updating of partitions, etc

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue-data-catalog

I read that the Glue Data Catalog needs a Crawler to run to see any new partitions, or to use the new `enableUpdateCatalog` feature for AWS Glue ETL.

If, however,

- running native Spark Jobs on EMR and having selected Glue data Catalog as the Spark persistent MetaStore, then,

  - I am assuming that if you have added a partition to a Spark table,

    - that AWS Glue Data Catalog will be updated automatically.

That is what I am seeking to confirm. Would seem odd if not, but...

> From the manual:
>
> AWS Glue provides a number of ways to populate metadata into the AWS
> AWS Glue Data Catalog. AWS Glue crawlers scan various data stores you
> own to automatically infer schemas and partition structure and
> populate the AWS AWS Glue Data Catalog with corresponding table
> definitions and statistics. You can also schedule crawlers to run
> periodically so that your metadata is always up-to-date and in-sync
> with the underlying data. Alternately, you can add and update table
> details manually by using the AWS Glue Console or by calling the API.
> You can also run Hive DDL statements via the Amazon Athena Console or
> a Hive client on an Amazon EMR cluster. Finally, if you already have a
> persistent Apache Hive Metastore, you can perform a bulk import of
> that metadata into the AWS AWS Glue Data Catalog by using our import
> script.

I am assuming that Spark on EMR will use that API.